# Sendmail not sending mail as generic alias

Tags: debian, smtp, email-server, sendmail

Following the advice in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/976762/50173) and the steps listed [here](https://sites.google.com/site/syscookbook/miscellaneous/sendmail), I've added the following to my `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` file and compiled it with `m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`.  The end of.mc file itself:

```
dnl # Default Mailer setup
dnl # Masquerading options
FEATURE(`always_add_domain')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`debian')dnl
FEATURE(`allmasquerade')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
FEATURE(`genericstable',`hash -o /etc/mail/genericstable.db')dnl
GENERICS_DOMAIN_FILE(`/etc/mail/generics-domains')dnl
MAILER_DEFINITIONS
MAILER(`local')dnl
MAILER(`smtp')dnl
```

I created the `/etc/mail/generics-domains` file with:

```
mylinodeboxdomain.com
avirtualdomain.com
```

And created the `/etc/mail/genericstable` file with:

```
virtualuser    noreply@avirtualdomain.com
```

And restarted the sendmail service.  Despite that, emails sent by `virtualuser` still seem to be coming from `virtualuser@localhost` rather than the desired `noreply@avirtualdomain.com`:

```
Received: from www.avirtualdomain.com (virtualuser@localhost)
    by mylinodeboxdomain.com (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) with SMTP id x6QIOIYY002415
    for <me@address.com>; Fri, 26 Jul 2019 14:24:18 -0400
```

I'm guessing my config is messed up, but as this is all new to me, I'm unsure what to change/remove.

Answer (score 1):

## Sendmail ident (and local ident like) info in `Received:` header

`Received: from www.avirtualdomain.com (virtualuser@localhost) …`

`virtuser@localhost` identifies local OS user executing sendmail.

For more details see secriprion of `$_` sendmail.cf variable.